# Do we have to malloc a struct?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Consider the following code:

```
struct Node {
    void* data;
    int ref;
    struct Node* next;
};
typedef struct Node* NodePtr;
```

I have found that I am getting segfaults whenever I try to do anything with NodePtr's fields. E.g.:

```
NodePtr node;
node->ref = 1;
```

So I allocated some space for the NodePtr, and now it seems to work fine.  Why is this?  My guess is that since node is just a pointer, it has no memory for its fields.

So I tried to initialize the NodePtr:

```
NodePtr node = {
    node->data = 0;
    node->next = NULL;
    node->ref = 0;
};
```

And well, I got this error:

```
error: expected â}â before â;â token
```

This boils down to four questions:

1. If my guess is incorrect, why doesn't it work if I don't use malloc()?
2. Why does my initialization not work?
3. Would initializing a struct offer memory on the stack and solve my problem?
4. If not, do I have an alternative to having to allocate memory for every struct I use?

Comment: You don't need `malloc`. For example, `struct Node n = {NULL, 42, NULL};`. You just have syntax errors all over the place.

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory if you're creating a non-pointer object.

Comment: Your `NodePtr` initialization isn't even correct C syntax, this can't be the code that you tried.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time, and invest a bit more to read things up, separate different concepts, do tests yourself first with all warnings of your compiler enabled...

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, I take responsibility for the syntax errors, but I think those are strong assumptions you're making about someone.  I noted the syntax error because it was part of my solution around using malloc.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A `struct` can be allocated automatically, but you are using a pointer to `struct` which will not allocate space for the destination `struct`. So that's the reason you get segfault.

The reason your initialization is incorrect is that you are initializing `struct` *members*, not the `struct` itself. Also you are doing this in a wrong way.

There are 2 ways for initializing a `struct` :

1. Using stack allocated `struct`:

   ```
   struct example {
     int foo;
   };
   int main() {
     struct example e;
     e.foo=1;
   }
   ```
2. Using heap allocated `struct` with help of `malloc()`:

   ```
   struct example {
     int foo;
   };
   int main() {
     struct example *e=malloc(sizeof(struct example));
     e->foo=1;
   }
   ```

Please note that when you are assigning value to a member of a `struct` from its pointer (heap allocated `struct`) you have to use '`->`' but for the normal struct (the stack allocated one) you have to use '`.`' .

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct: a pointer hasn't memory for the object it is supposed to point on its own, you need to allocate it yourself.

Anyway, as juanchopanza noted: you don't need a pointer and a memory allocation if you're dealing with a local object.

Both techniques follow:

```
typedef struct Node {
    void* data;
    int ref;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;
typedef struct Node* NodePtr;

int main() {

        NodePtr node = (NodePtr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node->data = 0;
        node->next = 0;
        node->ref = 42;
        printf("%d", node->ref);

        Node obj = {0,42,0}; // this is not on the heap
        printf("%d", obj.ref);
```

The other syntaxes you tried are **not** correct. Not even part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer isn't a struct. It's a number that tells C where the struct is located in memory. Any varible with type `NodePtr` is essentially a number.

How does it make sense, then, to set a variable of type `NodePtr` to a struct? A struct isn't a number!

When you declare it with `NodePtr node`, it might be set to some undefined value like 0. You can't access that memory, which leads to a segfault. Instead, you locate some memory to use with `malloc()` and make that variable point there where its fields can be used.

---

To respond to potrzebie's comment, it seems to work with strings but that's really just syntactic sugar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *a = "Does this make sense?";
  printf("%d\n", a); // %u is the correct one, but this is for illustrational purposes

  return 0;
}


> test.exe
4214884
```

Comment: It should make sense, you can do it with strings.

Comment: @potrzebie `char *x = "..."`? That's syntactic sugar, it's still a number and the string is stored somewhere else. Was that the reason for downvoting (if it was you)?